# How to Build specific module in a multi module spring-boot maven project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have create a multi module spring boot maven project.

But when I use

```
mvn clean package -pl module2 spring-boot:run
```

in console. It tell me that some class in module1 can not find.

But I have added the dependency in module2. The module2 is the final project.

the project structure is as follows.

parent project`s pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>multi-module</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>

</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    ...
</properties>

</dependencies>
    ...
<dependencyManagement>
    ...
</dependencyManagement>
```

the pom in module1:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>module1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

the pom.xml in module2:

```
<artifactId>personalinfo</artifactId>
<name>personalinfo</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you show the error, please?

Comment: Have you done a `mvn install` from root first ?

Comment: When I use mvn clean package in the root . It works good . But I want to know how to use "mvn clean package -pl [targetModule] spring-boot:run" to run spring boot module .

Comment: The error are as follows:`[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /src/main/java/com/example/dao/ClassInModule1.java:[12,29] package com.package.in.module1 does not exists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak your `pom`.

Parent pom:

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Module pom (containing your Main)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>Your mainClass</mainClass>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Pay emphasis on `Configuration > skip`

Comment: Well，Thanks. I have tried it, but did not take effect.

Comment: @bitscanbyte is right, it should work this way - have a look at the simple demo project I've created: https://github.com/drahkrub/spring-boot-multi-module

Comment: yes, you are right. The importance is      ````           <fork>true</fork>````

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @bitscanbyte is correct, but the configuration can be simplified:

**Parent pom**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Module pom** (the module in which the @SpringBootApplication is located)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

A simple demo project can be found here: https://github.com/drahkrub/spring-boot-multi-module