# Multiply Spring Boot projects maven run skip submodule

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, command-line, microservices

I have a multimaven Spring project with some parent pom. 
I want to run my apps with `maven spring-boot:run`, but one of the submodules doesnt have any main class. So parent pom run is failing because it cannot find the main class in the submodule "`common`".

What can i do to skip the "common" submodule in parent "`maven spring-boot:run`"?

Comment: If the sub-module is called common maybe try mvn -pl '!common' spring-boot:run

Comment: Otherwise perhaps try https://stackoverflow.com/a/49720768/9705485